# how to filter out any combination of two lists in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Let say I have list1 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and list2 ('a','b','c','d')
how can I filter out the rows where column1 equals any values in list1 and column2 equals any values in list2 at the same time?

Something like:

```
select * from table1
where (column1 not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and column2 not in ('a','b','c','d'))
or (column1 in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and column2 not in ('a','b','c','d'))
or (column1 not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and column2 in ('a','b','c','d'))
```

```
select * from table1
except
select * from table1
where column1 in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and column2 in ('a','b','c','d')
```

that would work in amazon athena

Thanks

Comment: Your second query would work with `or` instead of `and` -- although it would remove duplicates as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> filter out the rows where column1 equals any values in list1 and
>   column2 equals any values in list2

This means:

```
select * from table1
where (column1 not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and column2 not in ('a','b','c','d'))
```

**Edit**

> When column1 has a value in list1, filter out this row if column2 has
>   a value in list2

This means:

```
select * from table1
where (column1 not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) or column2 not in ('a','b','c','d'))
```